# What is the identity of this Rebel starship?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, rogue-one

There is this fat-looking starship with wing-like protrusions:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What is it? It reminds me of Separatist Muunilinst-class frigates but those are similar in size to Venator-class Star Destroyers, certainly much larger than the Rebel ships in question that seem to be closer to the size of those GR-75 transports.

Comment: Checked the [Star Wars databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank) of vehicles, and list of alliance ships present at the [Battle of Scarif](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Scarif), but I couldn't find anything resembling that particular ship.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's a **Braha'tok-class gunship**.

[image]

They've been used by the Rebellion since the start of the war, and were seen in Star Wars Rebels (Season 3 finale), as well as Episode VI - Return of the Jedi, just before the Battle of Endor.

[image: Massing at Sullust, before the assault on Endor]

[image: Battle of Attalon]

> The **Braha'tok-class gunship**, also known as the Dornean gunship, was an anti-starfighter gunship constructed by the Dornean Braha'ket Fleetworks Conglomerate for use by the independent Dornean Navy. Designed purely for military use, the ninety-meter-long craft bristled with weaponry, including turbolasers and concussion missile launchers. At first, the gunships were used to defend Dornea from the Imperial Navy, but in 4 ABY, two of them were sent to Sullust to join Admiral Gial Ackbar's Rebel Alliance Fleet, which was poised to strike at the Galactic Empire's second Death Star over the Forest Moon of Endor.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Braha%27tok-class_gunship